# Import an image into SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder

I am creating a report that will show a person's photo. I have field called RNumber in the dataset that corresponds to the image filename. I have the image source set to External and the set this as the path.

```
file:\\\\myserver\\dfs$\\shares\\MedicalEducation\\StudentImages\\Fields!RNumber.Value
```

This is not working dynamically, so I am trying to at least hard code one of the students with this path.

```
file:\\\\myserver\\dfs$\\shares\\MedicalEducation\\StudentImages\\R00737516.jpg
```

This image is showing up in design view, but not when I run the report. Is there a way to have it show a different photo for each person in the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out you need to specify the dataset.

```
"file:\\\\myserver\\dfs$\\shares\\MedicalEducation\\StudentImages\\" + First(Fields!RNumber.Value, "DatasetName")+".jpg"
```